# Order by meta date with a thousanth of a second defaults to post order

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, order

I have a custom post type query:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'paged'     => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_key',
// Here I am filtering posts further
    'meta_query'=> array(
        array(
            'key'   => '_assignment_type',
            'value' => 'sales_assignment',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
// This is the part that isn't working at all:
    'meta_key'  => '_homepage_publish_date',
    'meta_type' => 'datetime',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
);
query_posts($args);
```

The values on _homepage_publish_date are like this: 
2019-06-05 18:29:32.000

Whenever I try to get this order to work, the query returns the posts in the order where the posts were created.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was staring right at my tired face. After hours of hairpulling, I noticed I had used:

```
'orderby'   => 'meta_key'
```

I changed it to:

```
'orderby'   => 'meta_value'
```

fixed things right up... -_-'